# why does my django site url reveal the directory path on the server?

Tags: django, deployment, cpanel

I am deploying a django site for the first time to a cpanel server with phusion passenger on cloudlinux and i have discovered a weird phenomenon that can't be normal.

When I go to the site homepage it comes up as expected and when I click on any link the page loads fine but the url displays the full directory path to the app location on the server.

So, for example, rather than -

```
https://website.net/django_app
```

I get -

```
https://website.net/home/userdir/django_site/django_app
```

I don't even know where to begin to troubleshoot this as all the deployment settings were straightforward but I have clearly done something wrong somewhere.

Here is my passenger_wsgi.py file which I got from this site (https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-django-on-linux-shared-hosting) as the cpanel automatically generated passenger_wsgi did not work ;

```
  1 import os
  2 import sys
  3 
  4 import django.core.handlers.wsgi
  5 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  6 
  7 # Set up paths and environment variables
  8 sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
  9 os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_site.deployment_settings'
 10 
 11 # Set script name for the PATH_INFO fix below
 12 SCRIPT_NAME = os.getcwd()
 13 
 14 class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
 15     """
 16         Sets PATH_INFO from REQUEST_URI because Passenger doesn't provide it.
 17     """
 18     def __init__(self, app):
 19         self.app = app
 20 
 21     def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
 22         from urllib.parse import unquote
 23         environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME
 24         request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
 25         script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
 26         offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
 27         environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
 28         return self.app(environ, start_response)
 29 
 30 # Set the application
 31 application = get_wsgi_application()
 32 application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

I hope somebody can help
Thanks.